# Visual Studio 2010 opens "Create New Site" page in browser when I run "Start Debugging" instead of the site I am trying to debug

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-online, event-receivers, site, debugging

I am an Office 365 user and fairly new to Sharepoint.  I am trying to write a sandboxed solution for SharePoint online.  To do this, I have setup a local developer environment and am currently trying to debug event receivers.

When I start debugging in Visual Studio 2010, it opens a new browser instance but instead of opening up to the site I am trying to debug, it goes to the "Create New Site" page in the site collection.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You usually get this when the web application doesn't have any site collections available to it.  Do you have any site collections?

Answer (score 1):

Actually upon solution deployed, in Visual Studio 2010 under Properties window while selecting the Project node you get to specify where the solution is deployed. By default that should be the Web Application specified during Project Creation. If you are missing the site collection on that Url you would need either to create one site collection or simply update the actual property to point to another one where you are also Site Collection Administrator.